# How to transform this JavaScript in URL

Tags: javascript, php, url

I have this code :

```
function name() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/index.php",
      data: { id:  $("#id").val(),  date: new Date().getTime()}, 
    }); 
}
```

I would like to understand what is the translation to put in a URL. I have tried everything and it doesn't work. In my mind, it should be `index.php?id= ...` but no.

Comment: this is using the `POST` method. So you cant just put something in a browser url bar and get the same result. If this used the `GET` method then sure. If the index.php page is only setup to handle `POST` requests then send `GET` requests to it will do nothing.

Comment: as @Chausser stated, you are using the post method. with the get method the url would look like `/index.php?id=foo&date=bar`

Comment: So I can't get what I'm looking for with the post method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an alternative would be:

```
function name() {
    $.get('index.php?id=' + $("#id").val() +'&date ='+ new Date().getTime() +'',function(data){
        //work with the data callback here.
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function name() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/index.php",
      data: { id:  $("#id").val(),  date: new Date().getTime()}, 
    }); 
}
```

And receive id and date with $_GET['id'] , $_GET['date']...

If you use POST type, You have to receive with $_POST.